# Using RabbitMQ stomp adapter to relay message across subscriptions in different servers

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, stomp, spring-websocket

I am using Spring to setup Stomp server endpoints (extending AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer)

```
@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic","/queue")
        .setRelayHost(<rmqhost>);
}
@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/myapp/websockets").setAllowedOrigins("*");
}
```

The objective is that I can have multiple servers, and a client will connect to any one of them for a specific topic: /topic/topic-id-1

Any of the server (at a time) can send a message for this topic using Spring's SimpMessagingTemplate

```
messagingTemplate.convertAndSend(destination, message);
```

where destination = "/topic/topic-id-1". 
For ex: I have 2 server nodes and a client connecting to each one of them, subscribing to the same topic (/topic/topic-id-1). The objective is that if server 1 sends a message for topic-id-1, it should relay via rabbitmq to both clients subscribing to the same topic. I see a queue being created with routing key as "topic-id-1", but only the client connecting to the server sending out the message explicitly receives it. Am I missing something here? Isn't RMQ stomp broker supposed to relay the message send by one server for a subscription, across all the subscriptions for the same topic? Does the server need to do something else to get messages sent by other node?

Answer (score 4):

I met the same problem. After a whole day explored, I found the solution finally!! It's easy to configure though.

```
registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic/", "/queue/", "/exchange/") 
   .setUserDestinationBroadcast("/topic/log-unresolved-user") 
   .setUserRegistryBroadcast("/topic/log-user-registry")
```

The only thing you need to do is configure `setUserDestinationBroadcast` and `setUserRegistryBroadcast` when you enable the StompBrokerRelay. And it works!

I found the solution from [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/674). Thinks that guy!

Comment: By the way, the destination of these two options is casual, as long as it doesn't conflict with other destination.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly the same thing but I just solved a very similar problem. I posted my answer here: [Sending STOMP messages from other layers of an application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47250060/sending-stomp-messages-from-other-layers-of-an-application/47288074#47288074)

I decided to split the implementation of the relay server into it's own setup and then manually forward messages between the rabbitmq server and the websocket subscribers on each of the servers.

Hopefully this can be of some use for you.